# Variable refuses to be modified

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ExitPop() {
    if(PreventExitPop != false) {
        return "TEXT";
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload = ExitPop; 
</script>
```

as one could imagine, it asks the user if they're sure they'd like to leave.
I want to make it so that when they click on certain links, this code is disabled. How do I do this? I've tried setting `PreventExitPop` to false when the link is called, but that yielded no results. Lastly, I did the 4 spaces indent to make the above code indent like code, but it doesn't seem to work.
Assuming the first call changes the variable `PreventExitPop` to false, what am I doing wrong here:

```
<a href="http://www.mtrck.net/offer/79947|11640?data1=Track1&data2=Track2"> 
     <img  src="newpop1.jpg" alt="" width="532" height="570" onClick= "changeToFalse(false); MM_goToURL('parent',''http://www.mtrck.net/offer/79947|11640?data1=Track1&data2=Track2');return document.MM_returnValue"/>
</a>
```

Once again, sorry that I couldn't figure out how to create code blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Banzay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean up your code and define preventExitPop

```
var preventExitPop = true;
function exitPop() {
    if(preventExitPop) {
        return "TEXT";
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload = exitPop;
```

`changeToFalse()` is not a function - change the onclick paramater to `preventExitPop = false;`

Comment: Alright, so I tried this, but I've still got the same problem. Either it brings up the warning when they click the link, or it doesn't bring up the warning at all. Also, wouldn't I want to change the onclick parameter to false? I want the warning to not appear when they click on it? If I put them is as you recommended, it doesn't bring up the warning, if I flip them, it doesn't. Any tips?

Comment: Yes, flip the values. My bad. I'm on mobile right now, I'll try to find a solution when I get home.

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to figure this out for hours. HTML a language I haven't used in years.

Comment: The problem has been fixed, it was apparently a bad script. I've rewritten it and I'll mark this question as solved.